# Hooking a Java function with JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I've been searching for some time trying to find a way to hook a java method that isn't declared as native or with the `@Override protected native void` before the function declaration. I ran across a library called [Cydia Substrate](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/api/c/) that had a method named [MSJavaHookMethod](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/api/c/MSJavaHookMethod/) that is able to override any java method, however it is closed source and my attempts to reverse engineer the code in IDA have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Xposed framework (https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) is the one you should look for hooking java method.

Here is an example for how to hook a Java method: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/AndroidXposedHook